Tailwind multistep form progress, absolute position and flex layout
I have this component I am trying to build in tailwind.

It's proving tough to replicate with my best attempt being, here, which you will as the screensize drops keeps the middles 4 circles equidistant from one another but the gap between then first circle and them and the last circle increases. I'd someone to tell where I've gone wrong, or I can improve my effort.

<div class="container flex justify-center py-10">
  <div class="step1 relative w-full text-center before:absolute before:left-[50%] before:top-0 before:h-[10px] before:w-[200%] before:bg-brown after:absolute after:-top-1 after:left-[45%] after:h-[20px] after:w-[20px] after:rounded-full after:bg-mocha">
    <span class="mt-6 inline-block">step-1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="step1 relative w-full text-center before:absolute before:left-[50%] before:top-0 before:h-[10px] before:w-[200%] before:bg-brown after:absolute after:-top-1 after:left-[45%] after:h-[20px] after:w-[20px] after:rounded-full after:bg-mocha">
    <span class="mt-6 inline-block">step-2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="step1 relative w-full text-center before:absolute before:left-[50%] before:top-0 before:h-[10px] before:w-[200%] before:bg-mocha after:absolute after:-top-1 after:left-[45%] after:h-[20px] after:w-[20px] after:rounded-full after:bg-mocha">
    <span class="mt-6 inline-block">step-3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="step1 relative w-full text-center before:absolute before:left-[50%] before:top-0 before:h-[10px] before:w-[100%] before:bg-mocha after:absolute after:-top-1 after:left-[45%] after:h-[20px] after:w-[20px] after:rounded-full after:bg-mocha">
    <span class="mt-6 inline-block">step-4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="step1 relative w-full text-center">
    <span class="mt-6 inline-block">step-5</span>
  </div>
  <div class="w-full"></div>
</div>


for achieving progress we have to create line in every step with before or after below is the working example for the same I hope it will solve your problem

https://play.tailwindcss.com/yavimsOggq
